# My Heroku dyno is asking for http authentication

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm new to `Heroku` and I'm lost on this.

I updated the dyno via the `heroku git`. but when I go to the site, I just get a http authentication box, asking me to login.

I'm used to `AWS` where I can get in and find out why, so am a little lost here as to what is happening.

I'm taking over the code and support for another user, so I didn't set this all up either.

The code change I made was minor, in fact a couple of static files, so the django app would not be crashing, or have issues. I have changed nothing except some staric files.

This is from the log:

```
2016-07-08T21:28:54.182040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=wedclips-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=83b6454c-1566-4ab9-b8ef-5783211283df fwd="27.145.28.100" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=401 bytes=4654
2016-07-08T21:28:58.046855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wedclips-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=31de16de-e295-4a21-936e-f113ccd08e66 fwd="27.145.28.100" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=401 bytes=4654
```

Comment: Check how many dynos you are running and try restart them, here read this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: one dyno on this and I tried the restart and it didn't change anything. 
To me it looks like the web server is asking for authentication before passing the request on. I've seen this on Apache, but with Heroku, I have no idea how to see the machine set-up or whats going on under the cover

Comment: how are you logging into your `heroku` account, are you using `heroku CLI` from the terminal?

Comment: You have some middleware in django that is causing this to happen. Check your `settings.py`.

Comment: I am using the CLI. The setting file has not changed since a current working version. I've made no changes there. I can see no error codes being pushed out in the log either marking a middleware failure as that would have been my first thought as well

Answer (score 0):

From `Heroku` documents:

> The Heroku platform automatically routes HTTP requests sent to your
>   app’s hostname(s) to your web dynos. The entry point for all
>   applications on the Cedar stack is the herokuapp.com domain which
>   offers a direct routing path to your web dynos.

You will connect to your `heroku application` using `Heroku CLI` from the terminal running `heroku login`, enter your credential and log in, you can then work with your application. Read about `Heroku` HTTP Routing [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing), and about `Heroku CLI` [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command).

Comment: I have the command line working fine and have reviewed the code and the logs on the system. There are no error messages. However when I try opening the site, right away I get a Http authentication box pop up. I'm wondering if there is an issue with the static files on AWS and access there as the error message is on getting the site icon